# Compute the spectrum of an explicit integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-operators

Let $H = L^2[0,1]$. Define an operator $K \in B(H)$ by $Kf(x) := x^2 \cdot \int_{0}^{1} y f(y) \; \text{d} y$. Show that $K$ is compact and compute its spectrum.

I already showed that $ ||K || \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{15}}$ and as K is an bounded integraloperator  with continuous kernel $k(x,y) = x^2y$ it is also compact since it can be approximated by finite rank operators. To compute the spectrum we now want to know  for which $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ the operator $ ( \lambda Id - K ) $ is not invertible.
So I tried to solve the equation $ \lambda f(x) - x^2 \int_0^1 y f(y) \; \text{d} y  = g(x) $ for $f(x)$ but I didn't get anything useful on the paper and I dont know if thats the right way to do it.

How can I continue from here? Thank you very much !

Comment: Why did you set it equal to $g(x)?$

Comment: Notice that $K$ has rank one, so it has at most  one nonzero  eigenvalue.

Comment: I wanted to invert $ (\lambda Id - K ) $ for a suitable $\lambda$ so for every $g(x)$ in the range of $\lambda Id - K$ I wanted to find a $f(x)$ which is then $(\lambda Id - K)^{-1}g(x)$.

Comment: Like @Ruy stated, the compactness tells you that the only non-zero spectrum consists of eigenvalues. So, you can just look at the kernel of $\lambda I-K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As observed by Ruy in the comment, $Kf \in \mbox{Span}(x^2)$ for all $f \in L^2([0,1])$ and thus the unique nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda=\frac 1 4$.

In fact $K x^2=x^2 \int_0^1y^3dy=x^2 \frac 1 4$. This also prove that $K$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you very much! How do I see that there is nothing else in the spectrum. I see that there are no other eigenvalues but we learned that in the spectrum are not only the eigenvalues for some operators.

Comment: For a compact operator on an infinite dimensional space the spectrum consists of the eigenvalues plus zero (which may or may not be an eiganvelue).

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: A small little remark for following readers, it is $\lambda = \frac{1}{4} $ from the computation above ($\int_0^1 y^3 \text{d} y = \frac{1}{4} $)

Comment: @Holzi Thank you I have edited it.